# Calling a function to execute a data tree

Tags: python, data-structures, average, weighted-average

I already have a code for weighted score.

```
def weighted_total_score(student_scores):
    return((int(student_scores[0])*mid_1_weight)+(int(student_scores[1])*mid_2_weight)+(int(student_scores[2])*final_exam_weight)+(int(student_scores[3])*homework_weight)+(int(student_scores[4][0])*lab_weight)+(int(student_scores[5])*pr_1_weight)+(int(student_scores[6])*pr_2_weight)+(int(student_scores[7])*pr_3_weight)+(int(student_scores[8])*participation_weight))
```

I would like to call weighted_score in my new function overall_grade. How do i call weighted_score so that it gives me the correct answer? Currently when my code is executed, for example, I am getting F instead of C.

```
def overall_grade(weighted_total_score):
    weighted_total_score=int()
    if (weighted_total_score >=93):
        print("The overall student grade is A")

    elif (90<=weighted_total_score<93):
        print("The overall student grade is A-")

    elif (87<=weighted_total_score<90):
        print("The overall student grade is B+")


    elif (83<=weighted_total_score<87):
        print("The overall student grade is B")


    elif (80<=weighted_total_score<83):
        print("The overall student grade is B-")


   elif (77<=weighted_total_score<80):
        print("The overall student grade is C+")


   elif (73<=weighted_total_score<77):
        print("The overall student grade is C")


   elif (70<=weighted_total_score<73):
        print("The overall student grade is C-")



   elif (67<=weighted_total_score<70):
        print("The overall student grade is D+")



  elif (63<=weighted_total_score<67):
       print("The overall student grade is D")



  elif (60<=weighted_total_score<63):
       print("The overall student grade is D-")



  elif (weighted_total_score<60):
      print("The overall student grade is F")
```

Comment: what error are you getting. You can probably assign it to a variable and then do checks on variable.

Comment: "I'm not sure" is not a question. Please ask a clear specific question.

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana I am getting the wrong output. For example, when I should be getting C i am getting F

Comment: can you do a print of wegihted_total_score(student_scores) to see what it is returning?

Comment: @VikasMadhusudana it returns 78.48

Comment: Proper indentation might help

Comment: @JulienBernu I just edited the question

Comment: what is improperly indented @cricket_007

Comment: The fifth `elif` does not line up with the rest. Might just be how you formatted the question, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do i call weighted_score?

You call it like any other method...

```
def overall_grade(scores):
    score = weighted_total_score(scores)
```

**Note** Don't name your variables or parameters `weighted_total_score` because you have a method with that name already. If you referenced your local variables, they would [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) that method, which is generally not good and causes confusion for beginners.

---

The reason you get F is because `weighted_total_score=int()` is the same as  `weighted_total_score=0`, and your if statements go all the way to the bottom.

---

Also, tip, you actually don't need both boundaries in your conditions because the condition can "fall through".

And a suggestion, try to write simple methods, then build on top of them. Don't do too much at once. For example, make a method that only returns the letter grade, then have the method that prints the string and uses the result of the other method.

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    if (93 <= score):
        return "A"
    elif (90 <= score): # already < 93
        return "A-"
    elif (87 <= score): # already  < 90
        return "B+"
    # ... etc
    else:               # < 60
        return "F"

def overall_grade(scores):
    weighted_score = weighted_total_score(scores)
    print("The overall grade is {}".format(get_letter_grade(weighted_score)))
```

Comment: I keep getting score not define as an error message :(

Comment: I can't see your code, but maybe if you read the [stacktrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace), I'm sure you'll figure it out :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Very much appreciated :) @cricket_007

Answer (score 1):

Problem is

```
weighted_total_score=int()
```

This will make weighted_total_score as 0

It should be

```
wt_score=weighted_total_score(student_scores)
```

Also change the variable name from weighted_total_score to something else as the function already has that name

Comment: I am getting student_scores not defined when trying that @VikasMadhusudana

Comment: You have a list and now you want to get the grade based on average. you have to pass the list to your method weighted_total_score(<your list>).

Comment: Where should I define the new variable wt_score? @VikasMadhusudana

Comment: you need not define you can simply say wt_score = weighted_total_score(score)